# Load png files in XNA

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, xna-4.0

I am trying to load all png files from smoe directory( named "bee") but getting an exception that dir. does not exist.
Also, i am sharing the code.

Plese help where i am doing mistake

```
    private List<string> LoadFiles(string contentFolder)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(this.Content.RootDirectory + "\\" + contentFolder);
        if (!dir.Exists)
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();

        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        //Load all files that matches the file filter
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.png");
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            result.Add(file.Name);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Is the file "bee" exists in your system???

Comment: Where are the files? Isolated Storage, in the XAP or somewhere else?

Comment: yes "bee" alredy exist and path is "E:\Dated\23.09.11\XNA\WP7\WordGame\WordGame\WordGame\WordGame\bin\Windows Phone\Debug\Content\bee"

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes need to be escaped. e.g. `"C:\\path\\to\\some\\directroy\\"`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Path.Combine to build paths
2. if you have not selected "Copy to output" in your assets, you won't find that ".png" in that folder.

if your game path is "c:\game\source" and your content project path is "c:\game\content", the content folder you are trying to open, will be "c:\game\source\bin\x86\Debug" and there should be only .xnb files.